# Class WebTestCase not found when checking debug:autowiring

Tags: php, symfony, class, testing, load

When checking `php bin/console debug:autowiring`, I get the following errors:

```
In FileLoader.php line 168:

  Class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase not found in /vagrant/mysymfony/app/config/services.yml (whic
  h is being imported from "/vagrant/mysymfony/app/config/config.yml").


In WebTestCase.php line 17:

  Class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase not found


In WebTestCase.php line 21:

  Class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase not found


In KernelTestCase.php line 24:

  Class PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase not found
```

The error is due to the following file:

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is part of the RestExtraBundle package [1].
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this[1] source code.
 *
 * @license    MIT License
 * [1] https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaRestExtraBundle
 */
namespace AppBundle\Test;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase as BaseWebTestCase;

/**
 * @author William Durand <william.durand1@gmail.com>
 */
abstract class WebTestCase extends BaseWebTestCase
{
    protected function assertJsonResponse($response, $statusCode = 200)
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            $statusCode, $response->getStatusCode(),
            $response->getContent()
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $response->headers->contains('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
            $response->headers
        );
    }

    protected function jsonRequest($verb, $endpoint, array $data = array())
    {
        $data = empty($data) ? null : json_encode($data);
        return $this->client->request($verb, $endpoint,
            array(),
            array(),
            array(
                'HTTP_ACCEPT'  => 'application/json',
                'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
            ),
            $data
        );
    }
}
```

The file is in the following directory structure:

```
.
├── AppBundle.php
├── Controller
│   ├── DefaultController.php
│   └── FooController.php
└── Test
    └── WebTestCase.php
```

And that `WebTestCase` class is used in the following file:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class FooControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testFooAction()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/foo');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertJsonResponse($client->getResponse());
    }
}
```

Which is in the following path inside the `tests` directory:

```
.
└── AppBundle
    └── Controller
        ├── DefaultControllerTest.php
        └── FooControllerTest.php
```

The tests run without any kind of problem, and I actually discovered this error by chance. If I remove that file and any references to it from the tests then I can check `debug:autowiring` without any hassle. However I can't figure out what I am missing here. I guess it has something to do with file placement or something, but I don't really know. Can you lend me a hand please?

Also, if I didn't check that command, I wouldn't have noticed these errors. In order to avoid committing code to a repository which generates this kind of errors in the future, does Symfony log these errors somewhere? Or do I have to manually check every `debug` command?

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

Add contents of `vagrant/mysymfony/app/config/services.yml`

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'
```

Comment: What is the content of this file: `/vagrant/mysymfony/app/config/services.yml`?

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev I just edited the main question.

Comment: Well... I don't see any errors. Try to execute `composer dump-autoload`. LMK if it'll help you.

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev it didn't seem to work. However, moving the `Test` folder out of the `AppBundle` folder and modifying the namespaces accordingly seems not to give any errors... But I don't think that's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a piece of advice from the Symfony IRC channel. A person named Remco told me to include the `Test` folder in the `excludes` of `services.yml`. Now running `debug:autowiring` doesn't give me any errors.

I told him to answer my question here but apparently he doesn't have an StackOverflow account so I'll write it up myself, but all the credit goes to him. Thank you. I would also like to thank Nikita for his time and help.

The `services.yml` would look like this, in case somebody else faces the same problem:

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests,Test}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'
```